# Figuring Out Pin-Header Size for Socket from Datasheet + Ordering Specific Pin-Header Size

Tags: datasheet, pins, header

I ordered a 24 pin component socket for an Arduino Pro Micro. The specific one can be found here:

https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/575-11044624?r=575-11044624

However, when I received my Arduino ([https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01MTU9GOB/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MTU9GOB)) the male pin headers that came with it were too big to fit the tiny holes in this socket. Unfortunately, I already soldered the socket into the mechanical keyboard I am building and therefore need to find pin headers that fit the holes of this socket. However, I'm confused at how to search for pin headers that fit the specification on the datasheet:

https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/273/090-259652.pdf
(Manufacturer Number: 110-44-624-41-001000)

The Sleeve (Pin): 200 µ” Sn --> Which I think is the size? But I'm not sure how to match that to a pin header size.

When I search on DigiKey for male pin headers, the only measurements that I'm seeing are: Pitch, Row Spacing, Contact Length, Overall Contact Length, and Insulation Height. None of these seem to be what I need to specify.

Any suggestions on: 
(1) How to figure out the size of the pin-header I need? and 
(2) How to purchase male pin-headers with a specific size?

Thanks, 
~Z

Answer (score 1):

Answer to Question 1 - From the manufacturer's data sheet for that part, you need circular pins 0.015-0.025 in. or rectangular pins 0.010 * 0.018 in. (See picture below from data sheet)

[image]

Answer to Question 2 - Use the parametric search on your favorite vendor's web site.

Answer (score 0):

Std  0.1" pitch "headers" 12 pin  with tin plating (Sn 200u") requires 0.1" header sockets 12 contacts.
[image]

Connectors, Interconnects  > Rectangular - Headers, Receptacles, Female Sockets > 0.1" pitch > 12 contacts>  Sullins Connector Solutions PPTC121LFBN-RC .

Next you need a solder sucker or wick to remove the solder and wrong socket.

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/sullins-connector-solutions/PPTC121LFBN-RC/S6100-ND/807231   Tin plate
https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/sullins-connector-solutions/PPPC121LFBN-RC/S7045-ND/810184  flash gold plated